# How to get left top coordinate of rect area accurately when the image is zoomed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var offset = $('#slider1 img').offset();
 initDraw(document.querySelector('#slider1')); 
 function initDraw(canvas)
 {
  function setMousePosition(e) {
   var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
   if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
    mouse.x = ev.pageX - offset.left;
    mouse.y = ev.pageY - offset.top;
    
   } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
    mouse.x = ev.clientX + offset.scrollLeft;
    mouse.y = ev.clientY + offset.scrollTop;
   }

  };

  var mouse = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   startX: 0,
   startY: 0
  };
  var element = null;

  canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
   setMousePosition(e);
   if (element !== null) {
    element.style.width =Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
    element.style.height =Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
    element.style.left =(mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
    element.style.top =(mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
   }
  }

  canvas.onclick = function (e) {
   var i=0;
   if (element !== null) {
    element = null;
    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
    console.log("finsihed.");
   } else {
    var $rectangle = $('.rectangle');
    console.log("begun.");
    mouse.startX = mouse.x;
    mouse.startY = mouse.y;
    element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className ='rectangle para';    
    element.title =($rectangle.length + 1);    
    element.style.left =mouse.x +'px';
    element.style.top =mouse.y +'px';
    canvas.appendChild(element)
    canvas.style.cursor ="crosshair";
    
    /*$('.rectangle').clayfy(
    {
     type : 'resizable',
     minSize :[15,15],
     maxSize :[2600,2300],
    });*/     
   }
   
  }
 }
```

```css
.rectangle 
  {
   border: 1px solid black;
   position: absolute;   
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider1" class="imgart" style=" height: 480px;width: 1127px;overflow:auto;">
       <img border="0" src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/natural_beauty_highdefinition_picture_166133.jpg" width="auto" height="auto" alt="jQuery Image slider" >                 
      </div>
```

"I finished drawing the rectangle area over the image and get the coordinate of left and right of the rectangle area using javascript.But, when Image is zoomed coordinate of left,top of rectangle area changes."

Comment: Event is triggred on "mouse move".Not in mousedown

Comment: can any help me